# create huge dataset file for performance testing

Tags: java

I have a file with records which resemble the examples below. I want to create a single file with a million records with the same data. How can I do that?

I am aware of file io in java where i can create and write to file. Is there any tool or better way to do this to get better performance?

```
test;abc;tyr;ytu4;ytur<root><MessagePayload><abc><AlertCode>try</AlertCode></root>
test2;abc3;tyr4;ytu;ytur<root><MessagePayload><abc><AlertCode>ret</AlertCode></root>
test2;abc4;tyr4;ytu4;ytur<root><MessagePayload><abc><AlertCode>tue</AlertCode></root>
```

Comment: Is there a requirement to create the file dynamically? If not - why not create it once and the reuse it. That way performance won't matter.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mena by "with the same data"?  Do you want a few records copied over and over or are you looking to randomly create similar records?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **DataFactory** library in order to generate random data that make sense : https://github.com/andygibson/datafactory

You'll find some example on Github.

Comment: duplicate  the dataset which ever i have given million tuples

Answer (score 0):

If you just need huge data, a simple shell script will do it.

```
$i=100000
while [ i -ge 0 ]; do 
   cat file.txt >> file.txt
   i=`expr $i - 1`
done
```